# ios - "libtool failed with exit code 1" after a clean

Tags: ios, sharekit, exit-code, armv7, libtool-xcode

I was working on a project and all were going well until I decide to clean my project.

The following errors appears only when I run my app on simulator (working fine on a real device) :

```
Libtool /Users/Yaman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Homeless-gujyzhsiwenufvedlinbbtrizcpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libShareKit.a normal i386
    cd "/Users/Yaman/Documents/iOS - App à vendre/Homeless/Submodules/ShareKit"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only i386 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/Yaman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Homeless-gujyzhsiwenufvedlinbbtrizcpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/Yaman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Homeless-gujyzhsiwenufvedlinbbtrizcpd/Build/Intermediates/ShareKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Static Library.build/Objects-normal/i386/ShareKit.LinkFileList" -ObjC -all_load -lCopy -lDelicious -lDiigo -lEmail "-lEvernote SDK" -lEvernote -lFacebook "-lFlickr SDK" -lFlickr -lFoursquareV2 "-lGoogle Reader" -lInstagram -lInstapaper -lJSONKit -lKippt -lLinkedIn -lLogout -lOAuth "-lOpen in Safari" -lPinboard -lPrint -lReachability "-lRead It Later" "-lSave to Album" -lShareKitCore "-lSina Weibo" -lSSKeyChain "-lText Message" -lTumblr -lTwitter -lVKontakte -o /Users/Yaman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Homeless-gujyzhsiwenufvedlinbbtrizcpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libShareKit.a

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified, -all_load invalid
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lReachability
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lReachability is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

I got these errors when running command `xcodebuild` directly from a terminal :

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Libtool "build/ShareKit.build/Release-iphoneos/Static Library.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libShareKit.a" normal armv7
    Libtool "build/ShareKit.build/Release-iphoneos/Static Library.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/libShareKit.a" normal armv7s
(2 failures)
```

Someone can figure out what's happened here ?

Comment: Okay, now i clean my project for real device, my app doesn't work anymore on simulator and devices .....

Answer (score 6):

I just got this error. The project works very well, you add a new lib and BAM, build failed.

I my case, Xcode5 had added some special `\"` around my `header search paths` values.

Like that :

```
\"$(SRCROOT)/myproject/Libraries/lib\"
```

Quite impossible to find out, but when spending hours to find where is the problem, I finally tried to change to

```
$(SRCROOT)/myproject/Libraries/lib
```

And the build success came back... thanks Xcode!

Answer (score 3):

The first error note says that compiling [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) failed, because `Reachability` is missing. I'd propose that you check your compiling environment has latest (or compatible) version of the library.

That's why `libShareKit.a` mentioned in last error note is missing and compiling your app failed. Try to compiling ShareKit alone and when it's done, try again the whole app.